# How to load cross-domain image faster using file_get_contents and base64_encode?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I need to load images faster to my web app from facebook or flickr. I use php file_get_contents and base64_encode function to get photo cross-domain and pass the image data to html5 canvas. All other processings are done client-side and I am happy with that.

You can try it here : http://onlinephotomashup.com

**The problem is delay in loading photo to my app.**

I have researched on cURL and file_get_contents to see which is faster and i concluded that they do very little in loading photo faster. So I move to base64_encode which encode the photo into text whose size is increased to more than 30% of the size of the photo. So I think my problem is here.

I want to base64_encoding the photo with less size than the size of original photo so that loading is faster. How to achieve that ?

Comment: Can't you load a normal image and copy it over into your canvas?

Comment: ok i can load it for read purpose but can't write or edit on it as the image is to be loaded from other domain.

Comment: @sumen can't you copy the image into something on the client side that can be edit'd or written?

Answer (score 0):

May be, gzip output of base64_encode? And send appropriate header to clients browser so it would ungzip the data.

Comment: I think gzipping base64_encode is good for smaller images, but for larger images, there is not much difference in size.